# Android: Service stops when Activity is closed

Tags: android, service, bind

If I understand it correctly, 
bindService() with BIND_AUTO_CREATE will start a service and will not die until all bindings are all unbinded.

But if I bindService(BIND_AUTO_CREATE) at onCreate() and hit back button to close the 
activity, the service calls onDestroy() and dies also.

I don't call unbind() at anytime.
So is that mean when the Activity got destroyed, the binding got destroyed also and the service gets destroyed also?

What if I want the service to be always running, at the same time when the activity starts
I want to bind it so that I can access the service?

If I call StartService() and then bindService() at onCreate(), it will restart the service at every launch of Activity. (Which I don't want).

So I could I start service once and then bind next time I launch the activity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `startService` so that the service is not stopped when the activity that binds to it is destroyed.

`startService` will make sure that the service is running even if your activity is destroyed (unless it is stopped because of memory constraints). When you call `startService`, the `onStart` method is called on the service. It doesn't restart (terminate and start again) the service. So it depends on how you implement the `onStart` method on the Service. The Service's `onCreate`, however, is only called once, so you may want to initialize things there.

Comment: How can I communicate with the service from my activity? Say, I want to send notifications from the service to the activity when some work is done. The service performs some work periodically.

Comment: I call bindService() with BIND_AUTO_CREATE : Service stops when Activity is closed;      I call startService() , it ok. thx.

Comment: can u please elaborate bit on this ? i m facing issue with service

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution!

The problem is when you close your activity and your service is not configured as a foreground service, android system will recognize it as unused and close it.

here's an example where I added a notification :

```
void setUpAsForeground(String text) {
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mNotification = new Notification();
    mNotification.tickerText = text;
    mNotification.icon = R.drawable.muplayer;
    mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "MusicPlayer",
            text, pi);
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);

}
```

(A foreground service is a service that's doing something the user is actively aware of (such as playing music), and must appear to the user as a notification. That's why we create the notification here)

Comment: It would have been better if you shared the entire example, like what is `startForeground()` method ?

Comment: A Foreground Service in android is a background service which keeps running even after the parent application is closed. it takes (int id, Notification notification) as parameters.

Comment: Can you share its code ? Update it in your answer if you can.

Answer (score -5):

you can do it with BroadcastReceivers. you'll find a lot on google how to use them

Comment: are you suggesting intentService & broadcastReceiver?