# Start an android service when application is started

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is a way to automatically start an andriod service when application (without GUI) start ended. If there is a way to make this through the manifest? Or receive an ACTION via an intentReceiver?

Answer (score 1):

don't set a layout for that activity. And start a service in that activity. check out for services. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: I created an ctivity that start my service, but this one is stopped when i call finish in my activity. Is ther a way to make sur the service will be running after the activity has been destroyed.

PS : I call finish because the parent activity is waiting for a result (SetResult).

Comment: OnCreate method of my activity :
`@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
   
   startService(new Intent( this , MyService.class));
   setResult(RESULT_OK);
   finish();
 }`

Comment: when it starts a service, the service starts to run in the background. if you don't need to return to your activity you can remove the setResult. If you want to do something on finishing the service you can use a AysnTask. check AsyncTask.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. And check this answer also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251623/android-service-stops-when-activity-is-closed

Answer (score 0):

A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use. Each service class must have a corresponding  declaration in its package's AndroidManifest.xml. Services can be started with Context.startService() and Context.bindService().

[**Services....**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)