# android studio keep service running between activities

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development.

I am making an Android app that has a button that runs a service that extends Service to play all audios in the raw folder using MediaPlayer because I need to run the service in the background.

The problem is, when I'm switching between other activities (layout) that I've created, the audio automatically stops.

Can anyone tell me how I can keep the audio playing?

This is the part of the service I created.

```
    @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        final MediaPlayer m00 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_0);
        final MediaPlayer m01 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_1);
        final MediaPlayer m02 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_2);
        final MediaPlayer m03 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_3);
        final MediaPlayer m04 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_4);
        final MediaPlayer m05 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_5);
        final MediaPlayer m06 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_6);
        final MediaPlayer m07 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_7);
        final MediaPlayer m08 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_8);
        final MediaPlayer m09 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_9);
        final MediaPlayer m10 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_10);
        final MediaPlayer m11 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_11);
        final MediaPlayer m12 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_12);
        final MediaPlayer m13 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_13);
        final MediaPlayer m14 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_14);
        final MediaPlayer m15 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_15);
        final MediaPlayer m16 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_16);
        final MediaPlayer m17 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_17);
        final MediaPlayer m18 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_18);
        final MediaPlayer m19 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_19);
        final MediaPlayer m20 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_20);
        final MediaPlayer m21 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_21);
        final MediaPlayer m22 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_22);
        final MediaPlayer m23 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_23);
        final MediaPlayer m24 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_24);
        final MediaPlayer m25 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_25);
        final MediaPlayer m26 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_26);
        final MediaPlayer m27 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_27);
        final MediaPlayer m28 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_28);
        final MediaPlayer m29 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_29);
        final MediaPlayer m30 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_30);
        final MediaPlayer m31 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_31);
        final MediaPlayer m32 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_32);
        final MediaPlayer m33 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_33);

        Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                m00.start();
                m00.setNextMediaPlayer(m01);
                m01.setNextMediaPlayer(m02);
                m02.setNextMediaPlayer(m03);
                m03.setNextMediaPlayer(m04);
                m04.setNextMediaPlayer(m05);
                m05.setNextMediaPlayer(m06);
                m06.setNextMediaPlayer(m07);
                m07.setNextMediaPlayer(m08);
                m08.setNextMediaPlayer(m09);
                m09.setNextMediaPlayer(m10);
                m10.setNextMediaPlayer(m11);
                m11.setNextMediaPlayer(m12);
                m12.setNextMediaPlayer(m13);
                m13.setNextMediaPlayer(m14);
                m14.setNextMediaPlayer(m15);
                m15.setNextMediaPlayer(m16);
                m16.setNextMediaPlayer(m17);
                m17.setNextMediaPlayer(m18);
                m18.setNextMediaPlayer(m19);
                m19.setNextMediaPlayer(m20);
                m20.setNextMediaPlayer(m21);
                m21.setNextMediaPlayer(m22);
                m22.setNextMediaPlayer(m23);
                m23.setNextMediaPlayer(m24);
                m24.setNextMediaPlayer(m25);
                m25.setNextMediaPlayer(m26);
                m26.setNextMediaPlayer(m27);
                m27.setNextMediaPlayer(m28);
                m28.setNextMediaPlayer(m29);
                m29.setNextMediaPlayer(m30);
                m30.setNextMediaPlayer(m31);
                m31.setNextMediaPlayer(m32);
                m32.setNextMediaPlayer(m33);
            }
        };

        Thread listenThread = new Thread(r);
        listenThread.start();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: cannot help you without seeing some code.

Comment: Noted. I've added the code in the OP.

Comment: i think same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251623/android-service-stops-when-activity-is-closed

Comment: All audios at same time?? Don't understand what will be achieved? It has memory impact IMO.

Comment: Not at the same time. I used setNextMediaPlayer to play the next file after the current file ends.